# Alternative Definitions of a Sigma Algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm taking a maths for economics class which covers a little bit of measure theory but I'm slightly confused with a definition of a Sigma Algebra. I imagine this is a very basic question so I alpologise in advance.

In class we were presented with this definition.

$\mathbf{Definition:}$ Let $X$ be an arbitrary set. A collection $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $X$ is called a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ if it satisfies the following conditions:

1) $X \in \mathcal{A}$

2) $A \in \mathcal{A} \Rightarrow A^{c} \in \mathcal{A}$

3) $A_1,A_2,\ldots \in \mathcal{A} \Rightarrow \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n \in \mathcal{A}$

I understand this definition but I've seen 3) rephrased as

3*) $(A_n:n\in \mathbb{N})\subset \mathcal{A} \Rightarrow \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n \in \mathcal{A}$

and I don't understand why. Why is 3*) equivalent to 3)?. Why do we change from an element of $\mathcal{A}$ to a subset of $\mathcal{A}$.

I thought $(A_n:n\in \mathbb{N})$ was just shorthand for $A_1,A_2,\ldots$. I.e. a countable collection of sets.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are right, there is equality between the sets $\{A_1,A_2,A_3,...\}$ and $\{A_n\,;\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}.$

Answer (score 1):

They're saying the same thing: a countable collection of sets is in the sigma-algebra.

It's just a notation convention. You can talk of individual sets $A_1\in A$, $A_2\in A$,... OR you can say a set $B=\{A_1,A_2,...\}\subset A$, which means each of the elements of $B$ are in $A$.

Comment: thanks for the help. I understand your argument I think. But I would have thought that in that case the set $B=\{A_1,A_2,\ldots\}$ would be written as $B=\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ not $B=(A_n:n \in \mathbb{N})$. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you interpret a sequence $A_n$ of anything reasonable (real numbers, sets, etc.), then this can be written as the image of a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{A}$ by $f(n)=A_n$. Then $(A_n,n\in\mathbb{N})=\text{Im} f\subset\mathcal{A}$. The other formulation just takes each element of this set separately, writing $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n,\ldots\in \mathcal{A}$.